# To find Radius Of Convergence of Power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, limsup-and-liminf

**Question**

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ be a convergent series such that
$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$. Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $s$. Then what is the radius of convergence of series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n)a_nz^n$.

**My attempt**

$\limsup_{n\to\infty}  a_n = \frac{1}{R}$ where $R$ is the Radius  of Convergence. Since limit exists
$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L $.
$\limsup (a_nP(n)) =L\limsup P(n)$

I don't know how to proceed after this. I am stuck on finding limit supremum of $P(n)$. I am not good  in solving limit problems, so please apologize if my doubt is silly.

Comment: You did not apply Cauchy-Hadamard correctly.  $\limsup a_n$ does not exist (indeed, what ordering you are using on $\mathbb{C}$ to talk about $\limsup a_n$?)

Comment: Are you assuming anything about $L$?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos  Nothing . L is just a real number .

Comment: A *real* number? Why?

Comment: Sorry I mean a complex number

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) to remind yourself of how it works. You should be considering $\limsup_n \lvert a_n \rvert^{1/n}$ and $\limsup_n \lvert a_n P(n) \rvert^{1/n}$. If you try the problem again knowing this, can you solve it?

Comment: Thankyou so much @Izaak van Dongen I got the answer